How to create a Appointment Reminder API in twilio account for free using python?
I want to create an API for messaging in python with options to cancel,confirm,reschedule appointments prior to 48 hours before the appointment. Can someone give me ideas to develop this API fast and effectively for free.
I tried twilio flow charts. I created the flow chart and runned it in the visual studio but I didn't got any sms. but the status is active in output. I want to send sms with appointment reminders 48 hours to their scheduled appointment with options to cancel,confirm and reschedule their appointments. This should be updated in the app.

Can you show what you already tried and explain why that didn't work?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
